# Adding a custom Node JS version to openshift doesn't work for my app

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have written an application which needs Node.js >=  4.2.6
I'm using the OpenShift service and the default Node.Js version is 0.10. Installing this https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift is supposed to resolve this problem. So I followed the instructions and created a new application using:

rhc app create nodeapp nodejs --from-code=git://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift.git

So far so good. Next step - copy my project to the cloned git repository. Here's where I'm unsure if my approach is right (new to Node js). Because the cloned git already has a JSON package and because my app has its own JSON package in its root directory, I enriched the JSON package that came with nodejs-custom-version-openshift.git with my dependencies and set the engines to 4.2.6. The main is set to server.js. To run my app, I'm using "var variable = require('./myapp-master/test/test');" as the last line in my server.js. I copy the content of my app to the cloned repository (including node modules etc.) careful not to overwrite any existing config files like the JSON Package and then I use git push. The node version is installed properly according to the logs (upon build), servers.js is executed and it invokes my test.js. I can see in the app logs (app-root/logs) that test.js throws a specific error that indicates that the node js version is not >= 4.2.6.

When I log-in with PUTTY and write node -v, I get 4.2.6. When I navigate to my test.js and start it manually with node test.js, it runs normally. What am I doing wrong? I suspect I'm not handling the JSON packages properly (or my approach with starting my app from server.js is flawed). Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution to this: https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/issues/2